# YII IMAGE CACHE

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using IWI extension to cache image at time of display in yii framework . It's working fine but the problem is when I am updating a image the the past cache file and folder exists. Please help me to delete those past cache folder after update image.

**Edit:**

```
$img = $image_name[0]['image_name']; 
$p = 'images/'.$img;
$newpath = Yii::app()->iwi->load($p)->resize(100,300,Image::AUTO)->cache();
$newpath = explode('=',$newpath); ?> 
Image : <br/><br/> 
<?php echo CHtml::image($newpath[1],"image"); ?> 
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image'); ?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'image'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'image'); ?>
</div>
```

When i am updating a particular picture. Say I am updating a image whose id on the table is 1.the new picture is updating with new cache folders and previous cache folders exists.

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: $img = $image_name[0]['image_name'];
$p = 'images/'.$img;
$newpath =  Yii::app()->iwi->load($p)->resize(100,300,Image::AUTO)->cache();
$newpath = explode('=',$newpath);
?>
Image :
<br/><br/>
<?php echo CHtml::image($newpath[1],"image"); ?>
<div class="row">
 <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'image'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->error($model, 'image'); ?>
 </div>When i am updating a particular picture. Say I am updating a image whose id on the table is 1.the new picture is updating with new cache folders and previous cache folders exists.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What would be the expected behavior?
Are you saying that it uses the past cache instead of the new image?

Comment: No. When i am updating a particular image then previous cache folder of previous image remains on the server.I want to delete previous cache folder of previous image when update a particular image.

Comment: See my answer below. Unfortunately what you want to do isn't possible by default as the hash used to name the file/folders uses a time element (meaning it could be anything so you wouldn't be able to find it again without the original file you overwrite)

Comment: I see your answer but the added part is already written in generateBrief function. How can I cache images with image id inserted on table?

Comment: no generateBrief() method adds a timestamp to the needle (the file's modified time). This makes it impossible to know which directory/file to erase after you've overwritten the file. The point of my answer was to bypass that by ignoring the modified time, that way the new cached image will overwrite the old one and you will not have to remove them yourself. You can add any database information to the needle, like an ID for instance (or simply rewrite the needle to your standards). Hope I'm understanding you right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had a look at the IwI extension and I think I understand what it is you ask.

Unfortunately you can't achieve this out of the box. Iwi uses a caching id with the last modified date. This means that changing an image creates a new cached file/folder rather than being replaced based on a dependency rule.

I think the best option would be to extend `Iwi` and then override the `cache()` method (preferably using Yii's caching)

Here's an untested example:

**Extend `Iwi` class**:
This is very basicc and may not cover all your cases (ie: overwriting a file with another different file. Some of this is redundant but I did it so it was clear)

```
class MyIwi extends Iwi
{
    public function cache()
    {
        if (!isset($this->image["file"])) {
            return false;
        } 
        $cacheFolder = YiiBase::getPathOfAlias('webroot.images.site.cache');   
        $imagePath = $this->image["file"];
        $info = pathinfo($imagePath);


        //create unique ID (filename for cached image) using actions and path. then serialize and hash it.
        $needle = $this->actions;
        array_unshift($needle, $imagePath);
        $cachedFilePath = $cacheFolder."/".md5(json_encode($needle)).".".$info["extension"];

        //if cache file doesn't exist or is older than file then cache 
        if(  
           $this->createOrNone() //did not look into this, keeping because it was in original method
           &&
           (!file_exists($cachedFilePath)
           || 
           filetime($imagePath) > filetime($cachedFilePath))
        )
            $this->save($cachedFilePath);
        return Yii::app()->createUrl($cachedFilePath);
    }

}
```

Hopefully that will set you on the right track. Good luck